# Find the limit of the following series of normal random variables.

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Let $X_1,X_2,X_3,…$ be a sequence of i.i.d. $N(\mu,1)$ random variables. Then, find
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}E(|X_i-\mu|).$$

My thoughts:

I don't have any rigorous way to start, but just some thoughts. First I thought about writing out the expectations and $E(|X_i-\mu|)=\int(x_i-\mu)f_x(x_i)dx$ where $f_x(x)$ is the normal pdf. But I don't know is this approach helpful?

Next I tried to use some inequality. First thing came to my mind is to use Markov's inequality $P\{X\geq a\}\leq\frac{E(X)}{a}$, but it didn't help me to progress much further.

How can I solve this? So any ideas or help please. Thanks.

Comment: Hint: $X-\mu$ is normal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$X_i-\mu$ is a standard normal random variable, hence
$$ \mathbb{E}[|X_i-\mu|]=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|x|e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}\;dx=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\int_0^{\infty}xe^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}\;dx=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}$$
Therefore the sum is equal to
$$\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2n}\cdot n\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$
for all $n$.

Even without computing, we can see that the sum is independent of $n$ because the random variables are i.i.d.

Comment: Oh my bad. Didn't see that standard normal variable thing. Nice solution. thank you.